# ffmpeg - how to convert any media file to telegram opus audio note?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, telegram-messenger

I am looking for the correct ffmpeg command line to use with ffmpeg to convert any sound file (any format) to a mono Opus OGG audio file for use with Telegram to send it as a vocal note.

This is the MediaInfo of a telegram audio note from the android app:

```
Format                      : Ogg
File size                   : 5.59 KiB
Duration                    : 2 s 435 ms
Overall bit rate            : 18.8 kb/s

Audio
ID                          : 1901789286 (0x715B0066)
Format                      : Opus
Duration                    : 2 s 435 ms
Channel(s)                  : 1 channel
Channel positions           : Front: C
Sampling rate               : 16.0 kHz
Compression mode            : Lossy
Writing library             : libopus unknown-fixed
```

This is the MediaInfo of another one, but recorded on the Telegram Desktop app on windows:

```
Format                      : Ogg
File size                   : 26.8 KiB
Duration                    : 4 s 547 ms
Overall bit rate            : 48.4 kb/s
Writing application         : Lavf57.41.100

Audio
ID                          : 1739243463 (0x67AABFC7)
Format                      : Opus
Duration                    : 4 s 547 ms
Channel(s)                  : 1 channel
Channel positions           : Front: C
Sampling rate               : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode            : Lossy
Writing library             : Lavf57.41.100
```

I would like to put it in a `maketelegramnote.cmd` batch for convenient use.

Comment: The most simple suggestion: `ffmpeg -i input -c:a libopus -ac 1 output.ogg`. Try that first. Of course I recommend you use a recent `ffmpeg`: for Windows you can [download it from Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: i tried on a mp3 but the telegram client on android recognized it as music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also depends on how it is sent and should be sent in the form of a voice message and not a regular file. So you can use coding or robots.

Follow these steps:

1. In the first step, the audio file must be converted to the `Ogg Opus` format. This is easily possible with the help of `ffmpeg`:

   `ffmpeg -i test.m4a -c:a libopus test_libopus.ogg`
2. The audio file must be sent as a voice message, so I used this simple `Python` script:
   https://github.com/Fomchenkov/converter-voice-telegram-bot

I do not think I need to explain how to create a robot and insert it `TOKEN` in the file. Finally, send the file to your robot to receive the equivalent in the form of Voice Message.

As you can see in the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try also to install curl and then you can use this commands:

```
ffmpeg -i test.<ext.> -c:a libopus test.ogg
curl -s https://api.telegram.org/bot<botToken>/sendvoice -F chat_id=<chatId> -F voice=@test.ogg
```